# backslash- what it mean

Tags: php

What is difference between `\` and `\\`?

```
 echo $path_1="C:\wamp\www\practice\";
```

Output shows error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_VARIABLE or T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES or T_CURLY_OPEN

```
 echo $path_1="C:\\wamp\\www\\practice\\";
```

Output:

> C:\wamp\www\practice\

Instead of printing `C:\\wamp\\www\\practice\\` it prints `C:\wamp\www\practice\`

Answer (score 5):

Typically in programming the character `\` used between normal double quotes `"` is an escape character for special characters, making it a special character. So to display the `\` you have to escape it with another `\`.

I would also mention that the reason you received a Parse Error is because the ending `\` you used in your first example escapes the double quote so the end of line could not be parsed.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting string in single quotes (`'`)

```
echo $path_1='C:\wamp\www\practice\ '; //notice the space in the end
```

String inside `"` is checked for escape sequences and php variables. But string in `'` is echoed as it is. So escape all `\` when using inside `"` or write your string in `'`.

**Important note** string in `'` cannot end with a `\`. This would escape out the closing quote.